# Write array to the worksheet and repeat it n times

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on the code where I want to write 2 arrays (assigned in 'Input sheet) to 'Output' sheet n times, i.e. specifically 2 times in the loop. I want to use arrays because the range of the ids and its names can change (it can be much more).
To start with a simple example (with a small amount of data), the arrays are assigned acc. to data in 'Input' sheet:
[image]

These 2 arrays should be written to 'Output' sheet n times i.e.; They should be written once and then again in the loop i.e. 2 times. I want to do it in the loop to give it the flexibility of writing in the future e.g. 3, 4, n  times. In this example, I do it 2 times. Before each written array, there should be written a heading 'Title' and at the end of the written array should written text 'Total', **therefore this is my desired outcome:**
[image]

My code works only to write the 2 arrays for the first time but it does not write these 2 arrays for 2nd time. Instead, I am getting something else which is wrong:
[image]

This is my code:

```
Sub Write1()
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim Start_Row As Long
Dim End_Row As Long
Dim main As Integer
Dim lngRowCount As Long
Dim w_Output As Worksheet
Dim w1 As Worksheet

Dim intLastRow As Integer
Const RowStart As Integer = 3
Const ColumnID As Integer = 1
Const Column_Desc As Integer = 3

Dim arrID() As Variant
Dim arrDesc() As Variant

With ThisWorkbook
    Set w1 = .Sheets("Input")
    Set w_Output = .Sheets("Output")
End With

'***********************************
'arrays
With w1
    intLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'IntLastCol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    arrID = .Range(.Cells(RowStart, ColumnID), .Cells(intLastRow, ColumnID))
    arrDesc = .Range(.Cells(RowStart, Column_Desc), .Cells(intLastRow, Column_Desc))

'******************************************

main = 1
End_Row = 2  'this is the 2nd iteration to write arrays

For Start_Row = 1 To End_Row
    w_Output.Cells(main, 3) = "Title"

    main = main + 1

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrID, 1)

        If Len(arrID(r, 1)) > 0 Then

            'Write
                w_Output.Cells(r + 1, 3) = arrID(r, 1)
                w_Output.Cells(r + 1, 4) = arrDesc(r, 1)

        End If


    main = main + 1

    w_Output.Cells(main, 3) = "Total "

    Next r

    main = main + 4
Next Start_Row

End With

MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Does anybody know what I do wrong in my loop to make it work?

Comment: You're over-complicating this - just write the whole thing at once. I.e. the equivalent to `w_Output.Range("C17:D26:).Value = w_Output.Range("C2:D11").Value`

Comment: I have been trying without arrays (if this is what you mean by complicating). But I will have it also for a larger amount of data and that's why I want to use arrays. But arrays are not the problem, it is how to write these 2 inputs once again in the loop.

Comment: Note that I said "the equivalent". Get the source data into an array (all of it), then write the *whole array* to the destination. There shouldn't be a need to loop through array elements at all.

Comment: But that's what I did and so I got the result, but it does not work for the 2nd time (It should be written once and then, again as in the picture). Otherwise, I am not sure how else other then the loop can give the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, it turns out the I was simply supposed to use 'main' as the row to write to the sheet and not 'r' which is used for the arrays - this is part of the code where arrays are written to the sheet.

```
Sub Write1()
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim Start_Row As Long
Dim End_Row As Long
Dim main As Integer
Dim lngRowCount As Long
Dim w_Output As Worksheet
Dim w1 As Worksheet

Dim intLastRow As Integer
Dim IntLastCol As Integer
Const RowStart As Integer = 3
Const ColumnID As Integer = 1
Const Column_Desc As Integer = 3

Dim arrID() As Variant
Dim arrDesc() As Variant

With ThisWorkbook
    Set w1 = .Sheets("Input")
    Set w_Output = .Sheets("Output")
End With

'***********************************
'arrays
With w1
    intLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arrID = .Range(.Cells(RowStart, ColumnID), .Cells(intLastRow, ColumnID))
    arrDesc = .Range(.Cells(RowStart, Column_Desc), .Cells(intLastRow, Column_Desc))

'******************************************

main = 1
End_Row = 2

For Start_Row = 1 To End_Row
    w_Output.Cells(main, 3) = "Title"

    main = main + 1

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrID, 1)

        If Len(arrID(r, 1)) > 0 Then

            'Write
                w_Output.Cells(main, 3) = arrID(r, 1)
                w_Output.Cells(main, 4) = arrDesc(r, 1)

        End If


    main = main + 1

    Next r

    w_Output.Cells(main, 3) = "Total "
    main = main + 4

Next Start_Row

End With

MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
End Sub
```

It works perfectly.